# This PersistenceManager is not currently checkpointing

Tags: devforce

I keep getting

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This PersistenceManager is not currently checkpointing
   Stack Trace:
      at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.RollbackCheckpoint(Int32 pCount)
      at Anubis.ViewModel.ReassignCases.ReassignCasesViewModel.Reassign_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

and

```
IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManagerSaveException: Save failed - Query timeout expired
IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceServerException: Query timeout expired
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Query timeout expired
Stack Trace:
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.DoSaveDataSet(IEnumerable pDataRows, SaveOptions pSaveOptions)
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.SaveChanges(IEnumerable pDataRows, SaveOptions pSaveOptions)
  at Anubis.ViewModel.ReassignCases.ReassignCasesViewModel.Reassign_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)

  at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
  at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

while using IdeaBlade DevForce 3.6.2.2 version. Is there any way to troubleshoot this or any suggestions on what might be going on?

Additional Errors I get:

```
IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceServerException: Login timeout expired     
An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. 
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Login timeout expired
An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].
    Stack Trace:
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.HandlePersistenceServerException(Exception pException, Boolean pTryToHandle, PersistenceOperation pOperation)
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XFetchDataSet(IEntityQuery pEntityQuery)
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XFetch(IEntityFinder pEntityFinder, WorkState pWorkState)
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XGetEntities(IEntityQuery pEntityQuery, QueryStrategy pQueryStrategy, WorkState pWorkState)
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.GetEntities[T](IEntityQuery pEntityQuery, QueryStrategy pQueryStrategy)
    at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.GetEntities[T](IEntityQuery pEntityQuery)
    at Anubis.MainWindow.RefreshData()
    at Anubis.MainWindow.Save(Boolean DisplaySaveResult, String& error)
    at Anubis.MainWindow.Autosave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

and

```
IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceServerException: Communication link failure
   TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Communication link failure
TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
Stack Trace:
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.HandlePersistenceServerException(Exception pException, Boolean pTryToHandle, PersistenceOperation pOperation)
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XFetchDataSet(IEntityQuery pEntityQuery)
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XFetch(IEntityFinder pEntityFinder, WorkState pWorkState)
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.XGetEntities(IEntityQuery pEntityQuery, QueryStrategy pQueryStrategy, WorkState pWorkState)
  at IdeaBlade.Persistence.PersistenceManager.GetEntities[T](IEntityQuery pEntityQuery, QueryStrategy pQueryStrategy)
  at Anubis.MainWindow.RunMessageRetrieval(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
  at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The above seems to occur very frequently and brings our system to a halt.  Thanks for your input community

thanks
nick

Comment: here some other error I see often.  I posted them above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InvalidOperationException will be thrown if you call PM.RollbackCheckpoint and the PersistenceManager is not currently checkpointing.  You can check the PM.IsCheckpointing flag to see whether the PM thinks it is checkpointing.  If you think it should be, then try to determine why your code and the PM are out-of-sync:  Are you rolling back too far?  Have you previously cleared checkpoints?  Previously saved and not started a new checkpoint?  Accidentally using the PM in a non-thread-safe manner?

The query timeout during a save is a bit strange. DevForce will do a re-fetch after a save, but without the stack trace it's not clear that's the problem.  If you've implemented IPersistenceServerSaving or IPersistenceServerSaved then check if you're doing any queries there.

Comment: Thanks for answer back kim. I'll look into what you suggested. I added the trace stack to my original post and also some other very frequent error that I see throughout my day.  thanks again. nick

Comment: From the first 2 exceptions it looks like you're using a BackgroundWorker, which you need to use with care, as the PersistenceManager, like many other classes in DevForce, is not thread-safe.  Also check the debuglog file which DevForce automatically generates for you, it will usually have more detail on errors which occur on the "server" during a query or save.